# How to go from quadratic Element to Linear Element

Tags: finite-element-method, differential-geometry

I have created a 2D mesh as,

```
pts = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3, 2}];    
mr = ConvexHullMesh[pts]
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[mr]
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh, MaxCellMeasure -> 50]
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

Following `LineElement` consists of 3 numbers: Why not 2 numbers as it is a 2D line ?

```
mesh["BoundaryElements"]

(* out: {LineElement[{{2, 6, 12}, {3, 7, 22}, {1, 5, 18}, {4, 1, 19}, 
  {5, 3, 11}, {6, 4, 16}, {7, 2, 13}}]} *)
```

Similarly, `TriangleElement` of 2D mesh consists of 6 numbers, where I was expecting only 3:

```
mesh["MeshElements"]

(* out: {TriangleElement[{{5, 8, 3, 9, 10, 11}, {6, 2, 7, 12, 13, 14}, {8,4, 
   6, 15, 16, 17}, {5, 1, 4, 18, 19, 20}, {8, 5, 4, 9, 20, 15}, {6, 
   7, 8, 14, 21, 17}, {3, 8, 7, 10, 21, 22}}]} *)
```

If *Mathematica* inherently produces quadratic element then how do I convert or force it to return linear elements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is explained in the documentation. Specifically, see the second usage I've highlighted with a red rectangle.

[image]

It just means internally, *Mathematica* used quadratic line elements in generating the mesh. See more explanation in the details section which I've included for completeness. Same explanation holds for `TriangleElement`. To answer your new question please use the option `"MeshOrder" -> 1` when creating your mesh. so e.g.

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh, MaxCellMeasure -> 50, "MeshOrder" -> 1]
```

Now

```
mesh["BoundaryElements"]
```

> {LineElement[{{2, 4}, {3, 2}, {1, 5}, {4, 1}, {5, 3}}]}

Comment: @Matica You could try adding `"MeshOrder" -> 1` to your `ToElementMesh` expression. I haven't tested it though. Let us know.